# Comparator circuit identification

Tags: operational-amplifier

I would like to ask for some information about the op amp configuration in the attached photo. What is its function? Some kind of comparator I suppose, given the lack of feedback, but I cannot understand the purpose of the divider R7-R8.

[image: op amp circuit]

Answer (score 3):

This simulation should give you a clue as to the circuit operation.

[image]

[image]

I changed the capacitor value so the simulation time was reasonable. As you can see it makes the opamp output a positive direction pulse when the input signal changes level by a certain amount. With the component values shown this will detect a change of the input signal as low as about 20mV.

The R7 and R8 resistors assure that there is some voltage differential between the opamp inputs when the circuit has a steady state input. The resistor values also affect the timing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple switching circuit/comparator.  When the signal goes positive, the output goes to the positive rail.  When the signal goes negative, the output goes to the negative rail.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe its a comparator, without the ability to set hysteresis, which is what the positive feedback resistors would be for. As configured, the voltage, after a long while due to the large time constant formed by the RC filter (10 secs), the steady-state difference between the two opamp terminals would be Vin*[(1M/1M+10k) - 1], which is extremely small.

I believe this would create an unstable comparator as the slightest noise on the inverting input could trigger it to change states randomly.